# Canvas Draws Points it should not draw

Tags: javascript, canvas

Consider the following snippet: Why are there visible points outside the rectangle? 
Is the switching of the context color slower than the drawing of the rectangle?

```js
const templateCanvas = document.getElementById( "template" );
const tctx = templateCanvas.getContext( "2d" );
tctx.fillStyle = "red";
tctx.fillRect( 300, 300, 200, 200 )


const canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
const max = {
    x: 800,
    y: 800
};

const sites = [];
const points = 10000;
for ( let i = 0; i < points; i++ ) sites.push( {
    x: Math.floor( Math.random() * max.x ),
    y: Math.floor( Math.random() * max.y )
} );


const c = ( alpha ) => 'rgba(255,0,0,' + alpha + ')';
const c2 = ( alpha ) => {
    let colors = [
        'rgba(78,9,12,' + alpha + ')',
        'rgba(161,34,19,' + alpha + ')',
        'rgba(171,95,44,' + alpha + ')',
        'rgba(171,95,44,' + alpha + ')',
        'rgba(252,160,67,' + alpha + ')'
    ]
    return colors[ Math.round( Math.random() * colors.length ) ];
}

sites.forEach( p => {
    let imgData = tctx.getImageData( p.x, p.y, 1, 1 ).data;
    ctx.fillStyle = ( imgData[ 0 ] == 255 ) ? c2( 1 ) : c2( 0 );
    ctx.fillRect( p.x, p.y, 2, 2 )
} );
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    <canvas id="template" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: I think you want `Math.floor()` and not `Math.round()` in the random color picker.

Comment: Oh snap. That's really the solution. I feel dumb now. Too late (and a beer too much) for coding.

Thank you. Post this as an answer and I will gladly accept! @Pointy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is that your random color function sometimes returns an invalid color, because it's fetching from an undefined array element. That's caused by the use of `Math.round()` instead of `Math.floor()`:

```
return colors[ Math.round( Math.random() * colors.length ) ];
```

Because of that, every once in a while a bad color expression will be used for the fill style, and that will be ignored by the canvas mechanism. Thus you get some dots outside the area covered by red pixels (the square).